# Refresh with Ajax & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Intro:**

last Monday my webserver(Debian 8, Postgres 9.3, Apache 2 and PHP 5) have crashed :( The good new is I have backup of the data :)

From then I was installing the new server with this enviroiment: Debian 8, Postgrest 9.4, Apache 2, PHP 5

Today the server it's working fine and I have restored the data on the Postgres tables.

In the website I have a page with a table that I load data of Postgres query.

I select row with checkbox and I click a button to update the select registers in the database using Jquery + Ajax + PHP

**Problem:**

From I have re-installed the new server when I want update registers I don't show correctly. I have reload to page by hand to see correctly the updates.

For example: I select 8 registers, click the button to change a field, after it's executed the update.php only it's updated 6 and 2 not :( This happen at times, it's posible I select 8 and 5 good... or whatever

I use this code to reload the page after Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"updateEstado.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"estado": inputvalue, "id_fichaje": value, "saldo": arraySaldo[key]},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
        $('#canviestat').modal('hide');                     //Close window modal
        $('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll');   // Unchecked all checkboxes
        window.location.reload();                               // Recargar página
 }
```

});

I try a lot of things. Window.location.reload(true) -> without cache, also to redirect to initial page...

The php code:

```
<?php
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] != ''){

                include("db_tools.php");
                include("functions.php");

                $conn = dbConnect("localhost", "5432", "-", "-", "-");

                $estado = $_POST['estado'];
                $estado = Estado($estado);

                $id_fichaje = $_POST['id_fichaje'];
                $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];

                $username = $_SESSION['username'];

                $query = "UPDATE produccion.estado SET usuario='{$username}', estado='{$estado}', fecha_mod=now() WHERE id_fichaje = '{$id_fichaje}'";

                $result = pg_query($conn, $query);

                pg_close($conn);

        } else{
            ?>
            <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="text-center">
                  <p class='errorLogin'>La sessió no està activa, si us plau login <a href="login.php">aquí</a></p>
              </div>
        </div>
<?php
        }?>
```

It show this error in debug console in the register aren't upload correctly:

*jquery.min.js:4 XHR failed loading: POST*

Screenshot of debug network console:

[image]

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser to see how the request looks and what the actual response is. Also, check your error log to see if there's any clues in there.

Comment: I'm seeing the log of network but I don't know interpret the data. The logfile of the server already I have seen it but there aren't clues.

Comment: You should see `updateEstado.php` in the list of url's (after you executed the ajax). Click on it and check the "response" tab.

Comment: After ajax I haven't data of updateEstado.php the begining page is fitxatges.php with the jquery code. This call updateFitxatges by Ajax.

Comment: `updateFixatges`? In your ajax code, you're posting to: `updateEstado.php`. When that ajax is executed, you should see that path showing up under the network tab.

Comment: I would want to mean updateEstado.php . I check preserve log and I already see the fails and what URL. I have updated the post.

Comment: I have updated the post with a network log screenshot

Comment: There is a **syntax error** in your JS code. `success:function(data){` is missing a `}` and `$.ajax({` is missing a `);`.